# NeutralinoJS and Tauri backend services

Tags: electron, neutralinojs, tauri

I have used Electron for many years and like the fact that I can deliver a frontend app that has a bunch of backend services (connections to databases etc) that can be bundled in a dmg.

Electron is however a bit heavyweight and I have been looking at NeutralinoJs and Tauri to see if I can do the same. I've tried NeutralinoJs and it's certainly good for bundling a frontend app but it appears not have any mechanism for writing backend services and being written in C++, I suspect this is unlikely to happen.

Does Tauri allow you to write backend services in Rust - I can't tell from the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand how NeutralinoJS Works.

NeutralinoJS written in C++ starts a server on the specified port in `neutralino.config.json`

```json
"port": 0,
```

port 0 means Neutralino will chose a random port and start the server on it which serves all the content inside the folder we specified in the config file:

```json
"documentRoot": "/resources/",
```

After starting the server Neutralino uses the native `WebView` APIs to start a new window and tells the `WebView` to load the URL we want, in our case it will be `127.0.0.1` with the port we specified.

but since this `WebView` can't directly modify our storage or get information about the computer, Neutralino has some Pre-Defined APIs written in C++ to view and edit information on our computer.

since we use JavaScript, the Author of Neutralino has provided us a bridge using which we can access all the Pre-Defined APIs written in C++, and this bridge which provides us this stuff is `neutralino.js`.

`neutralino.js` handles all the communication between our `WebView` and the Neutralino Process.

the path of `neutralino.js` is also defined in the config file:

```json
"clientLibrary": "/resources/js/neutralino.js",
```

So if you want to work with the "Backend", you have 2 options you can either directly add those APIs in the Neutralino's Source Code or you can use a better way to work with BackEnd in Neutralino called "[Extensions](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/how-to/extensions-overview)".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a core feature. Here's their guide about Rust commands that can be called from Javascript:
https://tauri.studio/en/docs/usage/guides/command

According to their roadmap, [support for C-interop languages like Go, Nim, and Python is underway](https://tauri.studio/en/docs/about/intro#polyglots-not-silos).